# WSO2 ESB Performance Tuning For B2B example

Tags: wso2-esb

I am testing the Performance of a B2B example by sending FPML messages. I have tried with different no of nodes(2,3,4) with different no of messages. I can able to send upto 10,000 messages.But when i was trying with 50,000 messages with different no of nodes, i am getting the below error.

```
    ERROR - JMSMessageSender Error closing JMS Connection after send
javax.jms.JMSException: org.apache.activemq.transport.RequestTimedOutIOException
        at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:62)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.doSyncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1431)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.close(ActiveMQConnection.java:675)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSMessageSender.close(JMSMessageSender.java:250)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender.sendMessage(JMSSender.java:156)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportSender.invoke(AbstractTransportSender.java:112)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine$TransportNonBlockingInvocationWorker.run(AxisEngine.java:626)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.apache.activemq.transport.RequestTimedOutIOException
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.FutureResponse.getResult(FutureResponse.java:54)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.request(ResponseCorrelator.java:92)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.doSyncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1418)
        ... 8 more
[2013-03-05 22:34:14,351] ERROR - JMSSender Unable to create a JMSMessageSender for : null
javax.jms.JMSException: java.io.EOFException
        at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:49)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1377)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.ensureConnectionInfoSent(ActiveMQConnection.java:1481)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.createSession(ActiveMQConnection.java:323)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.createQueueSession(ActiveMQConnection.java:1257)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSOutTransportInfo.createJMSSender(JMSOutTransportInfo.java:378)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender.sendMessage(JMSSender.java:124)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportSender.invoke(AbstractTransportSender.java:112)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine$TransportNonBlockingInvocationWorker.run(AxisEngine.java:626)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:375)
        at org.apache.activemq.openwire.OpenWireFormat.unmarshal(OpenWireFormat.java:275)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.readCommand(TcpTransport.java:229)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:221)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:204)
        ... 1 more
[2013-03-05 22:34:14,357]  INFO - AxisEngine [MessageContext: logID=4daccf302df9e230a0e9d2d3c35edeb7306de0841cfe1b3f] Unable to create a JMSMessageSender for : null

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Dumping heap to /home/vithya/wso2/wso2esb-4.6.0/repository/logs/heap-dump.hprof ...
Unable to create /home/vithya/wso2/wso2esb-4.6.0/repository/logs/heap-dump.hprof: File exists
[2013-03-05 22:35:02,899] ERROR - JMSSender Unable to create a JMSMessageSender for : null
javax.jms.JMSException: Wire format negotiation timeout: peer did not send his wire format.
        at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:62)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1395)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.ensureConnectionInfoSent(ActiveMQConnection.java:1481)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.createSession(ActiveMQConnection.java:323)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.createQueueSession(ActiveMQConnection.java:1257)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSOutTransportInfo.createJMSSender(JMSOutTransportInfo.java:378)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender.sendMessage(JMSSender.java:124)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportSender.invoke(AbstractTransportSender.java:112)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine$TransportNonBlockingInvocationWorker.run(AxisEngine.java:626)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Wire format negotiation timeout: peer did not send his wire format.
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.oneway(WireFormatNegotiator.java:98)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.MutexTransport.oneway(MutexTransport.java:68)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.asyncRequest(ResponseCorrelator.java:81)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.request(ResponseCorrelator.java:86)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1366)
        ... 10 more
Exception in thread "ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///10.200.208.124:61616@33434" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2882)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:100)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:390)
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:119)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:200)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
[2013-03-05 22:35:02,901]  INFO - AxisEngine [MessageContext: logID=4daccf302df9e230aab5c2d3c35edeb7f06de0841cfe1b3f] Unable to create a JMSMessageSender for : null
[2013-03-05 22:35:02,903] ERROR - JMSSender Unable to create a JMSMessageSender for : null
javax.jms.JMSException: java.io.EOFException
        at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:49)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1377)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.ensureConnectionInfoSent(ActiveMQConnection.java:1481)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.createSession(ActiveMQConnection.java:323)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.createQueueSession(ActiveMQConnection.java:1257)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSOutTransportInfo.createJMSSender(JMSOutTransportInfo.java:378)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender.sendMessage(JMSSender.java:124)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportSender.invoke(AbstractTransportSender.java:112)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine$TransportNonBlockingInvocationWorker.run(AxisEngine.java:626)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:375)
        at org.apache.activemq.openwire.OpenWireFormat.unmarshal(OpenWireFormat.java:275)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.readCommand(TcpTransport.java:229)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:221)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:204)
        ... 1 more
[2013-03-05 22:35:02,906] ERROR - JMSSender Unable to create a JMSMessageSender for : null
javax.jms.JMSException: Cannot send, channel has already failed: tcp://10.200.208.124:61616
        at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:62)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1395)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.ensureConnectionInfoSent(ActiveMQConnection.java:1481)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.createSession(ActiveMQConnection.java:323)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.createQueueSession(ActiveMQConnection.java:1257)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSOutTransportInfo.createJMSSender(JMSOutTransportInfo.java:378)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender.sendMessage(JMSSender.java:124)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportSender.invoke(AbstractTransportSender.java:112)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine$TransportNonBlockingInvocationWorker.run(AxisEngine.java:626)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.apache.activemq.transport.InactivityIOException: Cannot send, channel has already failed: tcp://10.200.208.124:61616
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor.doOnewaySend(AbstractInactivityMonitor.java:282)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor.oneway(AbstractInactivityMonitor.java:271)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.oneway(TransportFilter.java:85)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.oneway(WireFormatNegotiator.java:104)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.MutexTransport.oneway(MutexTransport.java:68)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.asyncRequest(ResponseCorrelator.java:81)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.request(ResponseCorrelator.java:86)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1366)
        ... 10 more
[2013-03-05 22:35:02,906]  INFO - AxisEngine [MessageContext: logID=4daccf302df9e2305ab5c2d3c35edeb7906de0841cfe1b3f] Unable to create a JMSMessageSender for : null
[2013-03-05 22:35:02,909]  INFO - AxisEngine [MessageContext: logID=4daccf302df9e2302ab5c2d3c35edeb7106de0841cfe1b3f] Unable to create a JMSMessageSender for : null
```

Please help me to resolve this problem................

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 0):

Please refer document [1] and tune your ESB. Let us know if you are still getting this error.

1. http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Performance+Tuning

Comment: Hi I am using windows machine. i have done all the configuration changes in ESB, which is mentioned in the document. but -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m is not supporting in my machine. I have tried with -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m. But still i am getting the same error.